# BASH - Split file into several files based on conditions

Tags: bash, awk, sed, split, grep

I have a file (`input.txt`) with the following structure:

```
>day_1
ABC
DEF
GHI
>day_2
JKL
MNO
PQR
>day_3
STU
VWX
YZA
>month_1
BCD
EFG
HIJ
>month_2
KLM
NOP
QRS
...
```

I would like to split this file into multiple files (`day.txt`; `month.txt`; ...). Each new text file would contain all "header" lines (the one starting with `>`) and their content (lines between two header lines).

`day.txt` would therefore be:

```
>day_1
ABC
DEF
GHI
>day_2
JKL
MNO
PQR
>day_3
STU
VWX
YZA
```

and `month.txt`:

```
>month_1
BCD
EFG
HIJ
>month_2
KLM
NOP
QRS
```

I cannot use `split -l` in this case because the amount of lines is not the same for each category (day, month, etc.). However, each sub-category has the same number of lines (=3).

Comment: Are each subcategory (month1, month2, ...) composed of three lines as in your sample? If so, use `grep '>month' -A 3 > month.txt` & `grep '>day' -A 3 > day.txt` ; you mentionned categories aren't fixed-length but said nothing about subcategories

Comment: Yes, each section is composed of the same number of lines. I will add this to my question. Thank you!

Comment: `day, month, etc.` means there could be something like `>foo_1` also?

Comment: Yes, exactly. All have the same format:  `>name_number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per OP adding 1 more solution now.

```
awk -F'[>_]' '/^>/{file=$2".txt"} {print > file}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

```
awk -F'[>_]' '        ##Creating field separator as > or _ in current lines.
/^>/{ file=$2".txt" } ##Searching a line which starts with > if yes then creating a variable named file whose value is 2nd field".txt"
    { print > file  } ##Printing current line to variable file(which will create file name of variable file's value).
'  Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/^>day/{file="day.txt"} /^>month/{file="month.txt"} {print > file}' Input_file
```

Comment: For `awk -F'[>_]' '/^>/{file=$2".txt"} {print > file}'  Input_file`, is it correct that it first sets the record separator to `>` and then determines the name of the category in order to add each record to the corresponding text file? What are $1 and $2?

Comment: @Svalf, added explanation too here now, kindly do let me know in case of any queries here.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the record separator to `>` and then just set the file name based on the category given by `$1`.

```
$ awk -v RS=">" 'NF {f=$1; sub(/_.*$/, ".txt", f); printf ">%s", $0 > f}' input.txt

$ cat day.txt
>day_1
ABC
DEF
GHI
>day_2
JKL
MNO
PQR
>day_3
STU
VWX
YZA

$ cat month.txt
>month_1
BCD
EFG
HIJ
>month_2
KLM
NOP
QRS
```

Comment: good one, can also use `awk -F'_' -v RS='>' 'NF {printf ">%s", $0 > $1".txt"}'` or `awk -F'_' -v RS='>' -v ORS= 'NF {print RS $0 > $1".txt"}'`

Answer (score 0):

Since each subcategory is composed of the same amount of lines, you can use `grep`'s `-A` / `--after` flag to specify that number of lines to match after a header.

So if you know in advance the list of categories, you just have to grep the headers of their subcategories to redirect them with their content to the correct file :

```
lines_by_subcategory=3 # number of lines *after* a subcategory's header
for category in "month" "day"; do
    grep ">$category" -A $lines_by_subcategory input.txt >> "$category.txt"
done
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/hu8UrU).

Note that this isn't the most efficient solution as it must browse the input once for each category. Other solutions could instead browse the content and redirect each subcategory to their respective file in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic solution for `>name_number` format

```
$ awk 'match($0, /^>[^_]+_/){k = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2);
         if(!(k in a)){close(op); a[k]; op=k".txt"}}
       {print > op}' ip.txt
```

- `match($0, /^>[^_]+_/)` if line matches `>name_` at start of line

  - `k = substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)` save the `name` portion
  - `if(!(k in a))` if the key is not found in array
  - `a[k]` add key to array
  - `op=k".txt"` output file name
  - `close(op)` in case there are too many files to write
- `print > op` print input record to filename saved in `op`

Comment: This could be shorten to `awk -F'[>_]' '/^>/{file=$2".txt"} {print > file}' Input_file` too(not adding close logic in it) too, I believe.

Comment: yeah, I'll leave this as is so that your answer is unique :) mine was classic case of thinking too much ;)