# Splitting file into subfiles by multi-line alternation

Tags: bash, awk, split, line

I would like to split a multi-line input file (`file`) into two output files (`out1`, `out2`) such that every `n` lines are saved into one of the output files in alternating fashion.

For example, if `n=2` and `file` has a total of six lines, the first two lines of `file` are saved to `out1`, the next two lines are saved to `out2`, and the last two lines are again saved to `out1`.

```
$ cat file
foo
foo
bar
bar
baz
baz

$ cat file | sought_command out1 out2  # n=2
$ cat out1
foo
foo
baz
baz
$ cat out2
bar
bar
```

I believe this can be done with *awk*, and I would appreciate a pointer on how to start.

**Edit 1**:
I understand that the problem can be reduced to simply printing `n` lines, then not printing the next `n` lines, then printing `n` lines, ad infinitum, as a loop iterates through the lines. Coupled with setting an offset regarding from which line to start is sufficient to address the problem.

I understand that I can print every *third* line via `awk 'NR%3==1' file`, but how do I print every *three* lines?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647610/bash-split-file-into-several-files-based-on-conditions and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for getting started... you can work on line numbers using `NR` variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, inputting the numbers from 1 to 100:

```
seq 1 100 | awk -v n=4 'BEGIN{f=1} { if((NR-1)%n==0){f=1-f}; print > "out" f}'
```

Comment: You can use awks inbuilt conditional check for blocks instead of the explicit `if` here i.e `((NR-1)%n==0){f=1-f}{print > "out" f}`.

Comment: @123 Yes, agreed - thank you. There are lots and lots of ways of doing this :-)

Comment: `print > "out" f` is undefined behavior per POSIX. It'll do what you want in some awks and do something quite different in other awks. You need `print > ("out" f)` for portability .

Answer (score 1):

Could do this

```
awk -vn="2" '!((NR-1)%n){file=file=="file1"?"file2":"file1"}{print > file}' file
```

Just switches filename every n lines based on the ternary, and prints every line to the specified filename.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '(NR%2)==1{out = "out" ((c++)%2)+1 } {print " > " out}' file
foo > out1
foo > out1
bar > out2
bar > out2
baz > out1
baz > out1
```

Just change `" > "` to `>` to actually generate the output files.